# Maximum subarray problem brute force complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, brute-force

What is the runtime/memory complexity of the [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadane%27s_Algorithm) using brute force?

Can they be optimized more? Especially the memory complexity?

Thanks,

Comment: The algorithm is on the page you linked too so you could just inspect that to get the answer?

Comment: The algorithm in the page is not implemented via brute force. It is an O(n) and O(1) space algorithm. In fact I am not interested in this specific problem. It is just that the complexity analysis of the brute force approach to this problem is similar to many other problems in CS.

Comment: Given that you have to examine every item in the array at least once, it's not possible to do better than O(n). And, since you have to keep a running total, at least O(1) additional space is required. I'd say that the *algorithm* can't be improved. However, it's almost certainly possible to optimize the *implementation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force is Omega(n^2). Using Divide and conquer you can do it with Theta(n lg n) complexity. Further details are available in many books such as [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), or in various resources on the Web, such as [this lecture](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L02/L02.pdf).

Comment: brute force algorithm for finding a maximum sum has `O(n**3)` complexity, see [max_sum_subsequence](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem#toc1), so it is reasonable to assume that brute force for finding a maximum subarray can't have a better complexity.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113993/maximum-subarray-sum-modulo-m/56244322#56244322) you can use Kadane's algorithm which has O(n) complexity. An implementation in Java:

```
public int[] kadanesAlgorithm (int[] array) {
        int start_old = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        int found_max = 0;

        int max = array[0];

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            max = Math.max(array[i], max + array[i]);
            found_max = Math.max(found_max, max);
            if(max < 0)
                start = i+1;
            else if(max == found_max) {
                start_old=start;
                end = i;
                }
        }

        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start_old, end+1);
    }
```